# Are the 4 speakers on the iPadPro individually accessible?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-audio

That is, can I send 4 different signals to each speaker?

I've tried creating RemoteIO Audio Unit with four channels, but it seems my extra two channels are simply being discarded. This is in contrast to 2 channel output in a mono context, where both channels are mixed down to 1.

Any ideas? I haven't tried `AVAudioEngine` which doesn't seem to have a procedural output yet, but I could try playing a 4 channel `AVAudioPCMBuffer`. Or playing back a 5.1 surround sound video file?